# Why are my environmental variables adding whitespace?

Tags: python, linux, debian

I'm running Debian 12 and Python 3.9.16.

test.env:

```
export TEST="ABC"
export SECONDTEST="DEF"
```

I run `source test.env`

Then try to run this script in Python:

```
import os

test1 = os.getenv("TEST")
test2 = os.getenv("SECONDTEST")


def printenv(envvar):
    print(envvar)
    for char in envvar:
        print(char)
    print("done")

    if envvar == "ABC" or envvar == "DEF":
        print("ok!")
    else:
        print("Not ok!")


printenv(test1)
printenv(test2)

printenv(test1.rstrip())
```

The environmental variables add a new line character to the end. The output is:

```
A
B
C

done
Not ok!
DEF
D
E
F

done
Not ok!
ABC
A
B
C
done
ok!
```

Why are there newline characters in my environmental variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have MSWin line ends in the `test.env` script. It means each line ends with a `$'\r'` which is appended to the value assigned to a variable.

Run `fromdos` or `dos2unix` to fix the CR/LF issue.

Comment: I thought this might be the case, so I added the `"` quotation marks around the variables. Why does it still pick up the new line?

Comment: Same with any other character. `var="abc"d` assings `abcd` to `$var`.

Comment: Ah I see, so the `"` is literally just ignored/removed. Thanks!

Comment: Read about "quote removal" in `man bash` to learn more.

Comment: @gazm2k5 "Ignored" isn't right -- the quotes do something useful -- but "removed", certainly. (`export TEST="two words"` won't behave the same way without the quotes, f/e; they're used to establish a context in which the space isn't splitting into a second argument to `export`).